# How to add "Source packages" folder to a maven project (Netbeans)

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I'm new to maven, and to stackoverflow (Please like me <3 ) I've been looking for a while and searching in Netbeans as well but couldn't find it and feel so stupid for asking such a dumb question, but....

**how do I add a "Source packages" folder to my maven project in Netbeans**? You know, this folder for packages with java classes and code. I do not have the "Source packages" folder and I desperately want one.

When I simply click add a new folder, I can't see it in my projects tree.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Maven project then you can add the directory simply by creating the correct directory structure: The directory src/main/java must exist in your project.